# Apple App Store Submission Wait Time

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval, submission

I am about to submit my app to the Apple App Store, and I've read that it takes two weeks for Apple to review it before it goes live. However, in the pricing section of iTunes Connect, it is asking me when I would like to release my app, and one of the options is today. Would it still take two weeks, or will it release on the day given, even if it is less than two weeks away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Store approval process is a black box.  They may factor your plan release date into your approval priority, but just as likely will not.  I've always thought that was more for apps where you had a set up a huge marketing campaign, or were tied around a specific event (there's also priority reviews for this purpose).

If you wanted such considerations, I believe you'd put them in your notes with your submission.

I think the true purpose of the release date is on the chance you want your app to 'go live' on a specific day. I.e.: It gets approved on day X, but the actual release date is day Y, it will not appear in the store until day Y.

Good luck!

FYI: You can get a gauge for current review times, at this crowd-sourced site: http://appreviewtimes.com

Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107184/if-my-app-gets-approved-can-i-set-a-specific-release-date